# Full statement from ISO 8583

Tags: iso, iso8583

I would like to know if it is possible to do a full statement (between a date range) through ISO 8583, I have seen ATMs which do full statements and was wondering what method they used.  I know balance inquiry and mini statements are possible on a POS devise over 8583.

If it is possible does anyone have an information on the structure of the message, ideally for FLexcube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we did something similar to that back in 1999 in one of the banks, where we would send the statement data in one of the generic private use fields, where it would allow the format ANS 999

but that means you are either to restrict the data to less than 999 characters, or to split the data on multiple messages. and have a multi legged transaction.

you would have the following flow

- Customer request for statement on ATM
- ATM sends NDC/D912 message to ATM Switch
- ATM Switch look up account number after authenticating the card and forward the request to Core Banking Application
- Core banking application would generate the statement and format it according to predesigned template and send the statement data into a generic field (say 72)
- ATM Switch collects the data and formats it to NDC or D912 format where the statement data is tagged to statement printer (in NDC it is a field called q and the value should be ‘8’ - Print on statement printer only)

and on the field r place the preformatted data

however, it is not a good practice to do so, since we have faster means to generate a statement and send to email or internet banking. but this is the bank's preference anyways.

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon implementation,

I had implemented NCR central switch, where I incorporate initial checking stuffs in the Central application itself rather than passing everything to Auth Host.

My implementation.

1. ATM Sends (NCD) the transaction requests based on State Machine setup in ATM to Central Application.
2. Central does basic checkings such as Validity of BIN (initial 6 digit of card no.) and also checks if the requested amount of cash is available in the ATM etc.
3. The the Central App sends the packet (ISO8583/BASE24) is sent to the Acquirer for further processing.
4. Acquires Sends it to CA and then it goes to Issuer for Approval.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to develop an app that speaks with ATM NCR. Would you mind  to suggest any open source project to the server implementation, ISO and etc, please? Any that may help.

Comment: there are lot of open source projects for ISO but for NCR there are none, as that is proprietary protocol you can't create an open source project unless you have blessing/authorization from NCR.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Do you mean that is impossible to create Server to ATM NCR Software like APTRA NDC?

Comment: No it is possible. I did it back in 2007/08, if you have access to the specs. NDC protocol spec has all information you need. If you want to develop it bet the specs and get an ATM, you should be able to write it. I did the same. I was working for a bank they purchased bunch of ATMs and I developed the ATM Central application for them.

Comment: Do you remember any certain  title of PDF to search for? How to obtain these manuals? Thank you in advance!

Comment: As already suggested that is proprietary stuff can't be made available without approval from NCR. However, if you are interested in developing the central application please email: chandank@becloudready.com

Answer (score 1):

The mini-statement is not part of ISO 8583 (or MVA). It is usually implemented as a proprietary extension. Hence you need to go to an ATM owned by your bank, or, is part of a consortium of banks that share an ATM infrastructure with your bank.

Answer (score 1):

We implemented mini-statements in our ISO-8583 specification utilizing a $0.00 0200 (DE003 = 91xxxx) message and the statement data coming back from the host on DE125 on both Connex and Base24 and then modified our stateful loads to print the data at the ATM. 
Though full statements fell out of use years ago so we removed it to just be mini-statements now utilizing the receipt printer vs. full page statements. There is a limited number of entries and not all host support it but it is used today on NCR & Diebold ATMs. I've personally participated in the testing in getting it to work on Base24 and Postilion.

The mini-statement data we do print is 40 characters per line and prints about 10 transactions I believe.